# How to filter and show only selected items in datagridview?

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I have a datagridview and recently I got task to add a checkbox column (which I did) and a button (btnFilter) that will filter/show only selected rows so for example if I check only 4th, 5th and 6th row and click on 'btnFilter' the datagridview would show only rows 4,5 and 6.

So, the problem is how to show only selected (checkbox) rows.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far, how you have tried to solve the issue etc.

Comment: get the row indexes for selected rows, store them in a list, loop through all the existing rows from current datasource and check if the current row index matches the row index from the list if yes add the this row to a new datasource and after the loop .. bind this new datasource to datagridview

Comment: private void btnFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in groupsDataGridView.Rows)
            {
                if (this.groupsDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
                {
                    
                }
            }
        }

I think I managed to get it to check if checkbox is checked but I don't know what to do next ...

Comment: Here is the example of exactly what you need [GridView checkbox: Get Selected rows](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/GridView-with-CheckBox-Get-Selected-Rows-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to have a button which when clicked, a loop will be executed over GridView Rows. Within the loop we will check whether the CheckBox for that row is checked, if the CheckBox is checked then the Value from the GridView Row Cell and Cell controls like Label, TextBox, DropDownList, etc. can be fetched.

Here is the complete example with screenshots and source code in C# and VB

[GridView checkbox: Get Selected rows](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/GridView-with-CheckBox-Get-Selected-Rows-in-ASPNet.aspx)